# Amazon AWS SDK undefined reference to symbol 'BN_num_bits@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'

Tags: aws-sdk

I have amazon aws SDK installed in /home/X/AWS/{lib include}
I have openssl version OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

I've created a project in Qt using CMake.
I cannot pass the linker error:

undefined reference to symbol 'BN_num_bits@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/X/AWS/usr/local/lib/libs2n.a(s2n_dhe.c.o): 
undefined reference to symbol 'BN_num_bits@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so: 
error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My CMake looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(aws_example LANGUAGES CXX)
set(BIN_NAME aws_example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(aws_example
    main.cpp
)

###############################################################################
set(AWSP "/home/X/AWS/usr/local")
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  "/home/X/AWS/usr/local/lib/cmake" )

set_target_properties(${BIN_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath, -L/home/X/AWS/usr/local/lib")
###############################################################################
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/cmake/AWSSD")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-crt-cpp/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-http/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/s2n/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-common/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-cal/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-compression/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-mqtt/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-auth/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-sdkutils/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-event-stream/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-checksums/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/aws-c-s3/cmake")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/cmake/aws-cpp-sdk-s3")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/cmake/aws-cpp-sdk-core")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWSP}/lib/pkgconfig/aws-cpp-sdk-core")
set(aws-sdk-cpp_DIR ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
#find_package(aws-sdk-cpp)
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS s3)

###############################################################################
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(OPENSSL REQUIRED openssl)

if( OPENSSL_FOUND )
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS ">>>>>Using OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
    message(STATUS ">>>>>OpenSSL Folders ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()

 message(STATUS ">>>>>OpenSSL LIBS ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
target_link_libraries(aws_example
${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
-ldl -lpthread -lcurl -lz -L${AWSP}/lib
-laws-c-cal -laws-c-http -laws-c-s3
-laws-c-sdkutils -laws-c-mqtt -laws-crt-cpp
-laws-checksums -laws-c-compression -laws-c-auth
-laws-c-event-stream -laws-c-io -laws-c-common -ls2n)
```

I tried different linking ordering and the results varies from 200 linkage errors to one error I am running into right now. If I move the linkage to the bottom I get about 200 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the right solution. The change in CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(icp_app_man
${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
-ldl
-lpthread
-lcurl
-lz
${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES}  # <- this line
```